# Python won't assign the right value in simple "if" statement

Tags: python, django, django-admin, tastypie, django-signals

I have a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) project where users can create reservations.
I am using **Tastypie** for the API to which I submit simple `POST` request to  in order to create a reservation in the database.

Let's say we have a `request` like this(f*rom Chrome Network Tab*)

```
{passenger_name: "John", service_time_start: "12:12:12", flight_time: "12:12:12",…}
car_type: false
passenger_email: "john@gmail.com"
passenger_lastname: "Smith"
passenger_name: "John"
passenger_number: "5"
route_end: "Los Angeles"
route_start: "New York"
```

I'm using this code(`models.py`) at the **server-side**.
I want to **assign a car_type to the instance** with `Django Signals`.

```
''' Change car type for new reservation '''
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Reservation)
def smart_car_options(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    print 'SIGNAL: pass_no: ', instance.passenger_number
    print 'SIGNAL: car_type: ', type(instance.car_type)

    if instance.car_type == False:
        if instance.passenger_number <= 3:
            instance.car_type = 'CAR'
        if 4 < instance.passenger_number <= 8:
            instance.car_type = 'VAN'
        if instance.passenger_number > 8:
            instance.car_type = 'BUS'

    print "--------------------------------------------"
    print 'SIGNAL: pass_no: ', instance.passenger_number
    print 'SIGNAL: car_type: ', instance.car_type
```

As you can see, the `instance.car_type` is beeing set to `'BUS'`, when it should be set to `'VAN'`. **What am I doing wrong?**

Also, here is my console output for the `request`:

```
[20/Mar/2015 02:10:21] "POST /api/reservation/ HTTP/1.1" 201 736
[20/Mar/2015 02:10:40] "GET /forms/as_shuttle/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16237
[20/Mar/2015 02:10:52] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
SIGNAL: pass_no:  5
SIGNAL: car_type:  <type 'bool'>
--------------------------------------------
SIGNAL: pass_no:  5
SIGNAL: car_type:  BUS
[20/Mar/2015 02:11:06] "POST /api/reservation/ HTTP/1.1" 201 732
```

It looks like `passenger_number` is beeing set correctly, but it still **won't** assign the right value to the instance. It's always assigning the last value, **'BUS'**.

**PS:** The same code is working fine in the django admin.

Comment: try if elif else structure instead of if if if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that you are not converting `passenger_number` to an integer so the comparison operators are comparing between a string and an integer.

```
>>> "5" < 8
False
>>> "5" > 8
True
```

So try something like `num_passengers = int(instance.passenger_number)` and then do your comparisons against that instead.

Comment: This is most likely the case. Another problem that might occur, but doesn't seem to be occuring now, is that `false` may get converted to a string. Be sure to keep this in mind.

Comment: This ability to compare a string to a number seems to be specific to Python 2. In Python 3, it produces a `TypeError`.